# In Cocos2d-x, What is the difference between CC_SAFE_DELETE and CC_SAFE_RELEASE_NULL?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cocos2d-x, autorelease

I don't know the real difference between this two macros in Cocos2d-x

`CC_SAFE_DELETE` and `CC_SAFE_RELEASE_NULL`

Can anyone explain it to me? It probably can solve a few memory leaks I have in my game.

Here is an example of where I want to use it.

```
CoolLayer * CoolLayer::create()
{
    CoolLayer * pRep = new CoolLayer();
    if (pRep && pRep->init() )
    {
        pRep->autorelease();
    }
    else
    {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRep);
    }

    return pRep;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CC_SAFE_DELETE is defined as

```
do { delete (p); (p) = nullptr; } while(0)
```

basically used for deleting usual c++ declared objects you want to remove.

CC_SAFE_RELEASE is defined as

```
do { if(p) { (p)->release(); } } while(0)
```

*(edit just realized your question asks about CC_SAFE_RELEASE_NULL, its exactly the same except it also nulls out your pointer)*

This will decrement the reference count of your cocos2d-x objects which is used by cocos2d-x's reference counting construct, if an object hits a reference count of 0 it will be de-alloced for you.

Use safe delete for standard c++ things like vectors or arrays or whatever your custom classes may be.  Use safe release for anything to inherits from cocos2d::Object, as it has the native reference counting built in, making keeping track of your object references a little easier.

If you are unfamiliar with reference counting, it comes from the fact that cocos2d was originally created in objective-c, where reference counting is the norm, so after the port, they continued to use it for all their native objects.

Comment: forgot to mention the opposite of release is retain, retain increments your ref count, release decrements it.  If you are never calling retain, no reason to ever release, just use delete.

Comment: Ah! Perfect, you solved my doubt with this last comment, thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure why you'd ever want to use SAFE_RELEASE instead of SAFE_RELEASE_NULL, as it gives you potential access to an object that might have been deleted (or might not). This is a situation I've seen happen, and I'm curious to see what effect replacing all the SAFE_RELEASEs with SAFE_RELEASE_NULLs has on the engine.